# Whitespace in syntax table for comment delimiters in conflict with indentation and font lock

Tags: font-lock, major-mode, syntax-highlighting, syntax-table

The special file format of my software uses angle brackets as a delimiter and `#` / `#` as comment markers (note the whitespace after the first `#` and before the last `#`). I try to make a major mode to handle those files. I notice that the definition of the whitespace as a following character of the `#` enters in conflict with the indentation and font lock. I used the same syntax of my comment syntax table than the C/C++ style with `/*` and `*/`.

The MWE mode is

```lisp
(defvar my-very-basic-mode-syntax-table nil
  "Syntax table for `my-very-basic-mode'.")

;; My syntax table
(setq my-very-basic-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((my-very-basic-table (make-syntax-table)))
    ; Delimiters
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\{ "(}" my-very-basic-table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\} "){" my-very-basic-table)
    ; Comments
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# ". 14" my-very-basic-table)
    ;(modify-syntax-entry ? ". 23" my-very-basic-table) ; THE PROBLEM

    my-very-basic-table))

;; My indentation function
(defvar my-very-basic-mode-indent-offset 2
  "Indentation offset for `MY-VERY-BASIC-mode'.")

(defun my-very-basic-mode-indent-line ()
  "Indent current line for `MY-VERY-BASIC-mode'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((indent-col 0))
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line)
      (condition-case nil
          (while t
            (backward-up-list 1)
            (when (looking-at "[[{]")
              (setq indent-col (+ indent-col my-very-basic-mode-indent-offset))))
        (error nil)))
    (save-excursion
      (back-to-indentation)
      (when (and (looking-at "[]}]") (>= indent-col my-very-basic-mode-indent-offset))
        (setq indent-col (- indent-col my-very-basic-mode-indent-offset))))
    (indent-line-to indent-col)))

;; = My basic font-lock
(setq my-very-basic-font-lock
      (let* ((x-comments '("# " " #"))
             (x-comments-regexp (regexp-opt x-comments 'words)))
        `((,x-comments-regexp . 'font-lock-comment-face))))

;; My simple mode
(define-derived-mode my-very-basic-mode text-mode "my-very-basic-mode"
  "Mode for editing some kind of config files."

  (setq-local comment-start "# ")
  (setq-local comment-end " #")
  (make-local-variable 'my-very-basic-mode-indent-offset)
  (set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'my-very-basic-mode-indent-line)
  (set-syntax-table my-very-basic-mode-syntax-table)
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '((my-very-basic-font-lock))))

;; Myformat
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.myformat\\'" . my-very-basic-mode))

;; = End of mode
(provide 'my-very-basic-mode)
;;; my-very-basic-mode.el ends here
```

When I comment this line `(modify-syntax-entry ? ". 23" my-very-basic-table) ; THE PROBLEM`, I have a proper indentation but not the gray comment font (in `file.myformat`) :

```
# a block # <- NOT GRAY
{
  an internal block {
    some text {
      temperature 300
    } <- GOOD INDENTATION
  }
}
```

But if I uncomment the problematic line, it mixes with the indent calculation :

```
# a block # <- GRAY
{
  an internal block {
    some text {
      temperature 300
      } <- BAD INDENTATION
    }
}
```

Indent function is not my own, but I cannot find the source any more, unfortunately. My knowledge of Elisp is not that strong, and I cannot figure out what is missing. Any clue how to mix the two? I tried escaping with `?\` but that did not change. Any clue on how to make everything work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally took some time to investigate this, thanks to the awesome Emacs debugger. The problem was this exact line `(modify-syntax-entry ? ". 23" my-very-basic-table)`. That `.` in the syntax entry modified whitespace character to punctuation, spotted thanks to `C-h s`. So when `(back-to-excursion)` was called, there was an issue in the condition `(looking-at "[}]")` *if the rbrace was not on the first column*. The condition was thus nil and the indentation was not decremented. I changed to `(modify-syntax-entry ? "- 23" my-very-basic-table)` and it is now a nice whitespace. And it works like a charm now.